# Accurate geolocation range variables

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, geolocation

How can I get accurate geolocations coordinates for my app. For some cases I need to know where the phone is with an error ~8 meters.

Does swift location manager handles all the algorithmic stuff? Can it be made more accurate?

My app will target cities which may be a useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location accuracy delivered by Core Location will depend on a number of factors, in particular

- The quality of GPS signals; these can be degraded or non-existent indoors or underground.  Large buildings in a city centre can also reflect these signals causing location inaccuracy
- The availability of known WiFi networks
- How long location services has been active

You can request a specific level of location accuracy using the `desiredAccuracy` property on your CLLocationManager instance.  The default value is `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, which is the highest level of accuracy, but typically no better than 10m due to the limitations of the GPS signals.

When location updates are delivered to your `didUpdateLocations:` delegate method you can examine the `horizontalAccuracy` attribute for an indication of the positional accuracy of the location.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can get accurate geolocations coordinates for your app.  Like Paul said

> "The default value is `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, which is the highest level of accuracy"

but you can also use others if you would like such as `kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters`

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

var manager:CLLocationManager!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()


}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print(locations)

    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]

    let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude

    let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    }
```

Hope this helps!